# spring mvc tracing the referrer page

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

In annotation based spring controller. if  a user was on `url.com/first/page` and clicked a link or submitted a form pointing to  say `url.com/second/page`  .

How to make the `second/page` know the `url of /first/page` so that the `second/page` can

1) `redirect` the user to the `first/page` again when the form values are processed.

2) or show a b`ack button link` to the `/first/page`?

Edit 1 --

`request.getHeader('Referer')` is another but those I `think` are browser based on the mercy of browser. If the browser dont do it, we cant know. I wanted a way which is application wide. some how passing the url from one page to another

Edit 1 end --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use two below methods:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

or

```
request.getHeader("Referer");
```

In above methods you are trusting the browser behavior and also the container which make the request object available to you. I don't know why you don't want to use this method.

Or

you can get the current page/serlvet url save it in the session and use it in the second page.

```
 String requestUrl=request.getRequestURL();
 session.setAttribute("pervious_page",requestUrl);
```

Then in the second page:

```
session.getAttribute("pervious_page");
```

Comment: `request.getHeader('Referer')` is another but those I `think` are browser based on the mercy of browser. If the browser dont do it, we cant know. I wanted a way which is application wide. some how passing the url from one page to another

Comment: As far as I know, You can trust the above methods. If you don't want you can manually store the currentmurl in the session and use it in the target page.

Comment: you mean  one way is to catch each page on its visit by `request.getSession. page context. current page` or something and put it in a session attribute.  the next pages sees that . and so on?

Comment: got it. thanks. `request.getRequestURL().toString();` will show `theCompleteSiteAddress.com/section/page/bla`       but what If i only want to get  the `/section/pagge/bla` part only  ? I think I have to use substring after `/`