# How to find url which caused redirection from my redirected page?

Tags: java, jsp, request, httprequest, redirect

Here is a sample url. Say like,

```
https://example.com/test/<item_id>
```

which lands in the servlet `Test.java` from where it is redirected to a jsp page say `error.jsp` when error occurs

Now all I need from my jsp page is to get the source url (https://example.com/test/) which caused this redirection. How should i get it?

Any help would be most welcome ! Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150323/spring-mvc-tracing-the-referrer-page

Comment: You can use `[Referer` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14). Just code `request.getHeader("Referer");`

Comment: I'm getting null when trying to obtain it like `request.getHeader("Referer")` @JaySmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[javax.servlet.forward.request_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150406/6680585) helped me to get uri

```
String requestUri = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri").toString();
String sourceUrl = <domain_url> + requestUri;
```

Allows me to get entire url. Here I know base domain name hence I could get the entire url. But when it is redirected from some external site I'm not sure how to handle it.